# Docker returns "invalid reference format"

Tags: azure, docker, azure-sql-database

```
docker run -d — name MySQLServer -e ‘ACCEPT_EULA=Y’ -e ‘SA_PASSWORD=your_password123’ -p 1433:1433 mcr.microsoft.com/azure-sql-edge
```

I ran the above command in my terminal and it returns me the "invalid reference format".
I am running docker on an M1 chip Mac, which I am not sure if it affects anything.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you really using smart quotes (`‘’`) in your code? They are very likely to not be valid characters. Use "plain" single quotes (`'`).

Answer (score 0):

In the following command:

```
docker run -d — name MySQLServer -e ‘ACCEPT_EULA=Y’ -e ‘SA_PASSWORD=your_password123’ -p 1433:1433 mcr.microsoft.com/azure-sql-edge
```

Docker is trying to run the `—` image (the long hyphen before `name`). The `--name` option seems to have been altered by a text formatting tool somewhere. The correct command is:

```
docker run -d --name mysqlserver -e ‘ACCEPT_EULA=Y’ -e ‘SA_PASSWORD=your_password123’ -p 1433:1433 mcr.microsoft.com/azure-sql-edge
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this command workded:
`docker run -d --name mssql -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=password' -p 1401:1433 mcr.microsoft.com/azure-sql-edge`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).